# How to negate a literal string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match all arguments passed to a curl command like this:

```
curl -X POST --pro2gress -c --command=ASD --dos pl -slp "asd" --asdeee "asd \"hh\" s" "string"
```

to this

```
curl (-X POST) (--pro2gress) (-c) (--command=ASD) (--dos pl) (-slp "asd") (--asdeee "asd \"hh\" s") "string"
```

What I have so far matches everything but groups from *--asdeee TO string"*

```
/\-{1,2}[\d\w\-]+[\ \=]+[^\-]*/g
```

I'm looking for a way to look from " to " without stoping at a "

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

**(Edit)** The language is javascript

Thanks!

Comment: I'm working with javascript, editing the question as I write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match all options, use this:

```
--?\S+(?:[ ]+(?!-)(?:[\w-]+|(?<!\\)"(?:\\"|[^"\r\n])*+"))?
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pN4oQ1).

For JavaScript (no possessive quantifiers, no lookbehind), you can use this `lite` version:

```
var regex = /--?\S+(?:[ ]*(?!-)(?:\w+|"(?:\\"|[^"\r\n])*"))?/g;
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/iM6kO0).

- `--?` matches one or two hyphens
- `\S+` matches any chars that are not a whitespace character (spaces, tabs etc)
- The non-capture group `(?:[ ]*(?!-)(?:[\w-]+|"(?:\\"|[^"\r\n])*"))?` optionally matches...
- `[ ]+(?!-)` space characters not followed by a hyphen, then
- `[\w-]+` any number of hyphens and word characters (which include digits), or `|`
- `"(?:\\"|[^"\r\n])*"` a double-quoted string that may include escaped quotes

Comment: if it is not too much to ask, could you elaborate on the logic behind "(?:\\"|[^"\r\n])*" ? I specially do not understand why put \\" or anything not " or \r or \n.

Comment: `"` opens the double quote. Note that n the "full-flavor", at this stage I have a negative lookbehind to ensure that what precedes is not a backslash, but in this context it doesn't matter. Now that we're past the opening quote, what do we want to match? Either: escaped quotes `\\"` because those are valid in strings... Or any character that is neither a quote nor a new line character, which is the meaning of `[^"\r\n]` Of course if you are happy for your string to match across lines, remove the `\r\n`... We match those zero or more times, then we match the closing quote `"` Does that help?